# How to automatic zoom in ImageViewTouch

Tags: android

I am using ImageViewTouch library to zoom a image.

```
     <it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
           android:id="@+id/imageweb"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/bg_loading"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

With arbitrary image, I want to zoom automatic into the control which means the all image content will display full screen

```
ImageViewTouch img= (ImageViewTouch)findViewById(R.id.imageweb);
imageLocation.zoomTo(2.0f,20);// I want to to auto find default zoom vaule(not default 2.0f) to fill image content into screen.
```

How to automatic zoom in ImageViewTouch? I use setFitToScreen(true) but is not successful Thank you.

Comment: Edit post to include the problem in a visible manner

Comment: Are u got this problem solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, but if you want to zoom an imageView you can just add the `FitXY` scale in your xml file

Try this

xml file :

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
       android:id="@+id/imageweb"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/bg_loading"
       android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

java file :

```
ImageViewTouch img= (ImageViewTouch)findViewById(R.id.imageweb);
```

Comment: My question is how to fit content image into full screen.And I have found function to do it. But I don't know how to adjust step zoom with the ImageViewTouch. Assume that I double click on image. I can see image is larger. But step zoom very big. How to decrease the step zoom?